# Get the Application Running Path in App.xaml.cs

Tags: wpf

How can I get runnig path of my application from app.xaml.cs itself?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

and/or

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the [System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx) property to get the command line that started the application. Parse that with the [System.IO.Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) methods to extract just the executable's filename or full path.

```
var exeName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(
    System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]);
MessageBox.Show("This exe's filename is " + exeName);
```

Answer (score 0):

This always works:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath
```